# What is the difference between singlesig and multisig xpubs?

Tags: multi-signature, xpub, seedsigner

When exporting the xpub from my [SeedSigner](https://seedsigner.com/), I'm asked whether to export the "singlesig xpub" or "multisig xpub." I understand the use cases for each but from a technical standpoint, what's the difference?

Here's an example I've extracted by scanning the resulting QR Code:

- `[3fc54cd6/48'/0'/0'/2']Zpub…`
- `[3fc54cd6/84'/0'/0']zpub…`